# grunt-init conditional markup

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, gruntjs

I'm working on a grunt-init template and everything works great so far. But now I want to conditionally insert markup into my HTML/PHP files, based on the answers I give to the generator.

For example if I'm getting asked if I want to use jQuery and I type `Y`, jQuery goes into my JavaScript folder and the appropriate `<script>` tag gets added to my index.html. So inside of the index.html I need to write stuff based on the answers given during the setup.

I want to do the same thing in my CSS/SCSS files.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a great use for a Yeoman generator. If you haven't already experimented with Yeoman, [check it out](http://yeoman.io). In addition to being a tool that scaffolds a full application, pre-configured with best practices and common Grunt tasks, you also have the option to create your own "generator", to develop a prompt-based, custom build process that suits your needs. And for finer-grained tasks such as "insert this script in index.html," a "sub-generator" is used to do just that.

Developing a generator isn't restricted to something you intend to distribute, but can just be used to make your own common tasks more efficient. The [Generate a Generator guide](http://yeoman.io/generators.html) shows how you can do essentially just what you're describing, with little effort.

Grunt init templates are in the process of moving to Yeoman generators, so if you haven't already, now's a good time to play around with the Yo man! If you decide to try it out, let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I was _afraid_ that Yeoman would be **the** answer. Not that I don't like it – I think it's an awesome tool – but it seems way more complicated than the simple `grunt-init` way. But I didn't know that they're moving to Yeoman generators, so I think you're right - maybe I just have to switch before I get to comfortable with grunt-init.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and found that yes you can conditionally insert markup.

Grunt-init uses [grunt-template](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template) to process the template files. As you can see grunt-template just uses [Lo-Dash templates](http://lodash.com/docs/#template) under the hood and so you are able to execute normal JavaScript in between the delimiters, like so:

```
{% if(usesJQuery) { %}
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
{% } %}
```